# cannot convert parameter 1 from 'ATL::CString' to 'const wchar_t *'

Tags: visual-c++

For this line of code:

```
   int currentSnapshotHeight = _wtoi(ExecuteExternalProgram(L"current.png"));
```

I got this error:

```
Error 1 error C2664: '_wtoi' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'ATL::CString' to 'const wchar_t *'
```

How to fix?

Comment: Whats the prototype for ExecuteExternalProgram()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will work?

```
int currentSnapshotHeight = _wtoi(ExecuteExternalProgram(_T("current.png")));
```

Also check if Unicode setting of project are set as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int currentSnapshotHeight = _wtoi((wchar_t*)ExecuteExternalProgram(L"current.png").GetBuffer());
```